# Logic to Find the position of last node in Responys EMD Version

Tags: freemarker, responsys

`<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() != last()">
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>`

I am trying to use last() function in EMD Rpl function but that is not working

Comment: Use XSLT tag, that's not FreeMarker.

Comment: I want to impliment the same logic in freemarker is there any builtin function to find the position of last node in rpl freemarker language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Responys EMD configures FreeMarker. Also I saw Oracle sometimes uses their own FreeMarker fork, which is possibly based on some really old version. But I will assume it works as usual/up-to-date FreeMarker, but maybe it doesn't.

While `someElement['position()']` invokes the XPath function, it always returns -1 for some reason. But if you are listing elements with `#list`, you can use `?is_last`, like this (using https://try.freemarker.apache.org syntax for the data model).

Data model:

```
doc=<root>
      <a>text 1</a>
      <a>text 2</a>
    </root>
```

Template:

```
<#list doc.root.a as a>
  ${a}
  <#if a?is_last>
    That was the last one.
  </#if>
</#list>
```

which prints:

```
text 1
text 2
  That was the last one.
```

(There are also other fancy features for doing things based on the position of an item related to `#list`, like `#sep`, but see FreeMarker documentation.)

Outside `#list`, if you just have the element from somewhere, `myElement@@next_sibling_element[0]??` will return `false` for the last element.